# Replace ruby one liner with it do ; end block

Tags: ruby, regex, awk, gsub

I would like to know how I can replace in all my rspec files code like this :

```
describe ApiController do
  context 'article list exist' do
      #...
      it { should respond_with :success }

      it { should render_template 'refresh_article_in_article_list' }
  end
end
```

to

```
describe ApiController do
  context 'article list exist' do
     #...
     it do
         should respond_with :success

         should render_template 'refresh_article_in_article_list'
     end
  end
end
```

I was able to replace one with vim macro but not succeed with multiple lines.

With the help for [this post](http://effectif.com/ruby/update-your-project-for-ruby-19-hash-syntax#comment-1102781754) I've tried to do it in ruby gsub but I failed, I will keep searching :

```
"it { should respond_with :success }\n\nit { should render_template 'refresh_article' }".gsub(/(?<value>{.*})|(it {)|( })/, 'it do \k<value>\nend'))
=> "it do \\nend should respond_with :successit do \\nend\n\nit do \\nend should render_template 'refresh_article'it do \\nend"
```

Comment: How many of these do you have? Maybe just change them by hand and forget it?

Comment: @sergio-tulentsev I have probably more than 15000 one line like this. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF {
    prevSpaces = spaces
    spaces = $0
    sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"",spaces)
}
!inBlock && /it *{.*}/ {
    print spaces "it do"
    inBlock = 1
}
inBlock {
    if ( !NF ) {
        print
    }
    else if ( gsub(/.*it *{ *| *} */,"") ) {
        print spaces "    " $0
    }
    else {
        print prevSpaces "end"
        inBlock = 0
    }
}
!inBlock
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
describe ApiController do
  context 'article list exist' do
      #...
      it do
          should respond_with :success

          should render_template 'refresh_article_in_article_list'
      end
  end
end
```

Not sure what it does? Add some "prints" to see what the fields and/or variables are set to and read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and post specific questions if you have any.

Comment: Thanks @ed-morton for your answer. I've update the question for more context. I've try without success.

Comment: I was wrong. It works like a charm. I tested on a big file. Will definitly learn more ack to do it next time.